# Add and removing class for a tag by click event in php ul list cycle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Class doesn't add to anchor tag in ul list.

I got these errors:

> failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not
> found);

```
$(document).on('ready', () => { part of code is wrong.
```

I tried to connect jquery from the site.
I tried to change $ symbol to jQuery;
But no result.

jQuery code:

```
    $(document).on('ready', () => {
    const pageName = location.pathname.replace('/', '');
    const $activeMenu = $(`#templatemo_menu a[href="$ { pageName || 'index.php' } "]`);
    $activeMenu.addClass("current");
    } );
```

HTML and CSScodes:

```
<?$res = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menu");
    
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    
    do{
    
    $href = $row['title'];
    if( $href == 'Home'){
    $href = 'index';
    }
    if( $href == 'Contact Us'){
    $href = 'contact';
    }
    ?>
```

```
#templatemo_menu ul li a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 26px;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e4e1e1;
    font-weight: bold;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    }
    
    #templatemo_menu ul li a:hover, #templatemo_menu ul li .current {
    color: #fff;
    background: url(images/templatemo_menu_hover.jpg) center bottom no-repeat;
    }
```

Comment: I think you have a typo when you define `$activeMenu` in the first section. You cannot have a space in between the dollar sign and the braces, e.g. `${}` works, `$ {}` doesn't.